# Is patent US 5,504,055 expired?

Tags: expiration, legal-status, us5504055

Is patent [US 5,504,055 A](http://www.google.com/patents/US5504055), application Nr. 08/213,263 expired?
It was filed on 15 Mar 1994 and issued on 2 April 1996.

Comment: 21 years from issuance - I assume it is even more from filing. It seems reasonable to assume it expired.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 17 years from issuance?

Comment: Never mind, I see you mean it is now 21 years from issuance.

Answer (score 1):

For applications file prior to June 8th, 1995, the patent term is either 17 years from the issue date or 20 years from the filing date of the earliest U.S. or international (PCT) application to which priority is claimed (excluding provisional applications), the longer term applying. So this is either April 2, 2013 (17 years) or May 15, 2014 (20 years). Since May 15, 2014 is later, it is the expiration date for this patent unless there is an [extension](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-2700.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes its expired on May 15, 2014.

Comment: This answer is fine, but it'd be better if you could include how you found that information, so a future user with a similar question might be able to benefit for another patent.